# Multiple Excel Macro Runs in one VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a **VBscript** that contains `IF` statements to look for files, each file is different and if found runs an excel macro.

**Example:**

```
if file1 then
Rename file file1 to file1run
run open excel workbook1 run macro MYMACRO
if file2 then
Rename file file2 to file2run
run open excel workbook2 run macro MYMACRO
```

My issue is that if both files are available at the same time, workbook1 will rename the file and run the macro, but the second will only rename the file, it does not run the macro because one is already open, I cannot get the `VBscript` to wait for the macro to finish before checking for the next file.

Comment: Hello James, can you please check this link ? it will help alot http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Very difficult to check your code for errors without seeing the actual code...